# How to use QuantLib.IborIndex in python?

Tags: quantlib

QuantLib users.

I'm trying to use `ql.IborIndex(...)` using [this example](https://quantlib-python-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/indexes.html?highlight=libor) but for USD currency. However, I receive a type error of the following. How can I use this instead of `ql.USDLibor(...)`? Thank you.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
c:\Users\sc92841\repos\market-risk-model-validation\jira_models\abr409.py in 
----> 1 ql.IborIndex('USDLibor', ql.Period('1M'), 2, ql.USDCurrency, ql.UnitedKingdom(), ql.ModifiedFollowing,  True, ql.Actual360())

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\QuantLib\QuantLib.py in __init__(self, *args)
   5431 
   5432     def __init__(self, *args):
-> 5433         _QuantLib.IborIndex_swiginit(self, _QuantLib.new_IborIndex(*args))
   5434 
   5435     def businessDayConvention(self):

TypeError: Wrong number or type of arguments for overloaded function 'new_IborIndex'.
  Possible C/C++ prototypes are:
    IborIndex::IborIndex(std::string const &,Period const &,Integer,Currency const &,Calendar const &,BusinessDayConvention,bool,DayCounter const &,Handle< YieldTermStructure > const &)
    IborIndex::IborIndex(std::string const &,Period const &,Integer,Currency const &,Calendar const &,BusinessDayConvention,bool,DayCounter const &)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create an instance of the currency class you have to call it:

Try `ql.USDCurrency()` instead of `ql.USDCurrency`

You can check this site for references on object construction for the QuantLib Python module.

https://quantlib-python-docs.readthedocs.io

Comment: Ah, it's a call. Thanks.